# Optaplanner unable to remove ConstraintMatch

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner, drools-fusion

I've been getting this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The constraintMatchTotal (com.k.sp.rules/Minimum Consecutive Nights=0hard/0medium/0soft) could not remove constraintMatch (XXXXXXXXXXX) from its constraintMatchSet (XXXXXXXXXXX)

After debugging, I figured `ConstraintMatchSet` has same `ConstraintMatch` object which it's trying to remove right now(both has same hashcode and equals now), yet it's unable to remove it.

The reason I figured is, `ConstraintMatch.justificationList` has an inner list whose number of objects are different and hence it calculated different hashcode at the time of insertions so it's not able to remove now because set (hashtable) does not find object at current hash.

I think it'll solve my problem if I could avoid adding all "when" objects into justificationList of constraintMatch but dont know how to do it. Help?

Here's how my rule looks like:

```
rule "Minimum Consecutive Nights"
salience 20
    when
        $emp:Employee()
        $shifts:ArrayList(size>0) from collect (ShiftRequestPhase(getInterval()!=null && employee.equals($emp)))
        $constraintsPenality: Integer(intValue>0) from ($emp.checkConstraints($shifts,6))
    then
        $emp.breakLevelConstraints(scoreHolder,kcontext,6,$constraintsPenality);
end
```

Comment: When do you get that exception? Simply during `solve()`? In that case, presuming that your list elements don't violate the equals/hashcode contract, it's a bug - please create a jira (see "Get help" on optaplanner.org) and link it here. If you actually do something, such as addProblemFactChange(), please specify that first here in the question.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I'm pretty sure it's a bug. Yes it's during solve() and I only use id field in equals and hashcode(). No, I am not using addProblemFactChange().

Comment: Might be a bug indeed, please [create a jira with a reproducer](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER). Confirm that you've reproduced with the latest final version. Confirm that turning on turning on environmentMode FULL_ASSERT does not change the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the very same problem using Java 9 and newest Drools & Optaplanner Version (7.6.0-Final). I needed a very quick **hack** to circumvent this problem hence I simply disabled the ConstraintMatch collection. The  `AbstractScoreHolder`  Class allows setting an boolean in the constructor

`protected AbstractScoreHolder(boolean constraintMatchEnabled, Score zeroScore)`

The `constraintMatchTotal` is not necessary if you do not need the `IndictmentMap`. I simply disabled this. feature and it worked.

@GeoffreyDeSmet: Unfortunately i cannot provide an example for you but I narrowed it down to code lines with  `List() from collect (...)`  in the rule file. If i completely avoid those  `List()`  in my rules everything works fine. Maybe this helps?!