# Is bug ? Optaplanner unable to remove ConstraintMatch

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I encountered a problem, which is consistent with the problem on this link.
-> [Optaplanner unable to remove ConstraintMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501563/optaplanner-unable-to-remove-constraintmatch)

> Exception:
> org.optaplanner.core.api.score.constraint.ConstraintMatchTotal.removeConstraintMatch

I debugged, and both hashCode and Equals were rewritten, but errors were still reported.

Rule:

```
rule "scheduleFullTimeLimit"
     when
         $shiftList: ArrayList() from collect (
                     StaffAssignment(
                         shiftType != null
                 )
                 )
     then
         scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

I used collect in my rules.

Is this a bug?

Beg your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that the problem here will be with the `ArrayList`. ArrayList's `hashCode()` will change with every change to the collection. Therefore, you will get the exact message you're getting - OptaPlanner is trying to undo something which does not exist.

You'll have to figure out how to do whatever you're doing without the `ArrayList`. At the very least, don't let the `ArrayList` be the final thing in the rule, because I believe that is what lands it in the constraint matches in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, thank you for your reminder.
I have seen the implementation of ```org.optaplanner.core.api.score.holder.AbstractScoreHolder#registerConstraintMatch ```method in OptaPlanner,I have changed my mind to solve this problem